# How to change the width of the legend in nvd3 graph

Tags: javascript, css, nvd3.js

I'm using the legend whose width is occupying almost the entire chart space leaving no space for me add any text next to it.

I would like to reduce the width of the legend(show below) so that i can fit another legend next to it:

Something like:

400 Bad Request    403 Not ..    404 Not Found

500 Internal .....

Instead of:

[image]

I tried this:

```
 nv.addGraph(function() {
            chart = nv.models.lineChart().options({
                width: 100  //just random number

            });
        }
```

it reduced the width along with the width of the chart..

Is there any way to this using either css, or js???

Comment: Dude! I am facing similar kind of problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: try this: chart.legend..width(100).height(50).margin({top: 10, right:30, left:80, bottom: 50});  it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve a similar issue by changing the `chart.legend.maxKeyLength` property. That's the number of characters to display for each legend item. I believe it defaults to 20, so try lower than that.